# How to append numbers to relevant string JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add relevant indexed strings from array to numbers in div. Can someone help me please?

For example I want to append "one" from array to 1 in div.

I want result:

```
1one
2two
3three
4four
5five
```

```js
let array = [one, two, three, four, five]

$('button).click(function(){
//div append array
})
```

```html
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<button></button>
```

Comment: Will the order always match?

Comment: @mplungjan How does this snippet with syntax and reference errors help?

Comment: @Andreas - it was mainly for formatting reasons. And OP can see the console.errors they need to fix

Answer (score 1):

First fix your syntax errors. Missing quote on $('button) for example and missing quotes on the array elements

Then add a function to the .html

If the order of the array matches the order of the .test items, this is the simplest code

```js
let array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
$(function() { // on page load 
  $('button').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // just in case the button is in a form and not type=button
    $(".test").html(function(i) { // using function to get at $(this)
      return $(this).text() + array[i]; // or this.textContent+array[i] or $(this).html()+`<b>${array[i]}</b>` etc
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Vanilla JS

```js
let array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

window.addEventListener("load", () => { // on page load
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // just in case the button is inside a form
    // [...document.querySelectorAll(".test")].forEach((ele, i) => ele.textContent += array[i]); // for recent older browsers like Edge<v17
    document.querySelectorAll(".test").forEach((ele, i) => ele.textContent += array[i])

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Why `$(".test").html(...)` but `return $(this).text() ...`? Why `[......document.querySelectorAll(".test")]` when the returned `NodeList` already has a `.forEach()` method?

Comment: @Andreas Defensive coding - even quite new browsers do not have forEach on nodelist and OP can use .html(...html()) or .text(.text()) but if he wants 1<b>ONE</b> then he needs .html(...)

Comment: or this.textContent+array[i] or $(this).html()+\`<b>${array[i]}</b>\` etc

Comment: _"even quite new browsers do not have forEach on nodelist"_ - But then understand the spread syntax?

Comment: Every browser (IE is not a browser) that understands the [spread syntax](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_arrays) also provides a [`.forEach()` method](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_nodelist_foreach) on `NodeList`

Comment: IE is still s browser used by more than 10% of our users. Also edge < v17 supports spread and not forEach on nodelists

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this. In your click event handler callback, you simply iterate through all elements that match the `.test` selector, and then set their `innerText` to include the corresponding string from `array`, accessed by index:

```js
let array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach((el, i) => {
    el.innerText += array[i];
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<button>Add</button>
```

Comment: For any code that is requested in jQuery, you could answer with "You don't need jQuery for this."

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all elements with each. Use the index of the loop to append the correct word.

```js
let array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

$('button').click(function(){
   // Check every element with the class test
   $('.test').each(function(e){
    // Append current index of array
    $($('.test')[e]).append(array[e])
   });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: [No need for each](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63702729/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan, you are right. Going to upvote yours :)